# Authentication guard redirect doesn't work on children routes

Tags: angular

I am novice in angular, i bulding an app and handle my login service like this:

```
export class AfterLoginService implements CanActivate {

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>
{
    if (!this._tokenService.loggedIn())
        this.router.navigate(['login']);

    return this._tokenService.loggedIn();
}
```

and my routes is like this:

```
import {BeforeLoginService} from './services/before-login.service';
import {AfterLoginService} from './services/after-login.service';

export const routes: Routes = [
{
 path: '',
 redirectTo: 'dashboard',
 pathMatch: 'full',
 canActivate:[AfterLoginService]
},
{
 path: 'login',
 component: LoginComponent,
 canActivate:[BeforeLoginService]
},
{
 path: '',
 component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
 canActivate:[AfterLoginService],
 data: {
  title: 'Home'
 },
 children: [
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)
   },
   {
     path: 'buttons',
     loadChildren: () => import('./views/buttons/buttons.module').then(m => m.ButtonsModule)
    }
    // others child routes
   ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: P404Component }
];
```

Now if I try to access a protected path (/buttons, for example) without logging in, it redirects me to the login but if I put something else like "/buttons/any" the following is shown:

[image]

when I try to access a daughter route without logging I am not redirected by middleware, the daughter routes are like this:

```
import { ButtonsComponent } from './buttons.component';
import { DropdownsComponent } from './dropdowns.component';
import { BrandButtonsComponent } from './brand-buttons.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Buttons'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'buttons'
      },
      {
        path: 'buttons',
        component: ButtonsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Buttons'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'dropdowns',
        component: DropdownsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Dropdowns'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'brand-buttons',
        component: BrandButtonsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Brand buttons'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

children routes are supposed to abide by middleware and redirect me to login but I don't know what I'm missing, just like if I try to access some non-existent route (/bad_path/any) it shows the same thing and doesn't redirect me to 404 page as set it with the wildcard path, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little late, the error was that the base URL of my site was not like / (the  tag had the href with another url that I do not remember exactly) and therefore the angular location strategy did not work, the only thing what I did was change the base url to / so that all relative urls could be handled with pathLocationStrategy

Answer (score 1):

for children you have to use **CanActivateChild**, try this:

```
{
 path: '',
 component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
 CanActivateChild:[AfterLoginService],
 data: {
  title: 'Home'
 },
 children: [
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)
   },
   {
     path: 'buttons',
     loadChildren: () => import('./views/buttons/buttons.module').then(m => m.ButtonsModule)
    }
    // others child routes
   ]
  },
```

Definition on angular.io for caActivateChild

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a child
>   route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation will
>   continue. If any guard returns false, navigation will be cancelled. If
>   any guard returns a UrlTree, current navigation will be cancelled and
>   a new navigation will be kicked off to the UrlTree returned from the
>   guard.